# Scroll Bar Design

Tags: html

I want to do the styling of scroll bar. It's working in chrome but it isn't working in Firefox. How do I solve this?

Comment: Pleas read the following help pages: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you will have found the code for custom scrollbars is `::-webkit-scrollbar` using the webkit system

Unfortunately not all browsers support webkit, you'll find Webkit works on browsers such as Chrome & Safari but Firefox uses `-moz` and I.E. uses `-ms`. Because of this, scrollbar design will work on **webkit browsers only**. There is no -moz or -ms equivalent.

You can read more on the [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar) pages about scrollbar design

Comment: Yes, that's because there is no -moz-scrollbar there is only -webkit-scrollbar. Scrollbar design only works in -webkit supported browsers

Comment: i m using -moz-scrollbar then not working in firefox.... i m seraching the google in this problem but not solved it..

Comment: There is no solution for Firefox or IE, scrollbar design works on webkit browsers only such as Chrome and Safari. Any other browsers will not have the scrollbar design as they do not support it